# Spring MVC Using @RequestMapping on controller class with variable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, routes, mapping, request-mapping

I would like to write whole controller to work with entity.
I would like to declare the id of entity on class level and use it on each method. Here is the controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/job/{j_id}/instance")
public class JobController extends GenericController {
    private final String htmlDir = "job/";

    @RequestMapping(value="{i_id}/open", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView open(@PathVariable Long instance_id) {
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView(htmlDir  + "instance");
        result.addObject("instance_id", instance_id);
```

**Here I would like to use variable `j_id` from `@RequestMapping`**

```
        return result;
    }
}
```

Can I achive this? Please help. Give me some code snippest please.

Comment: You can get it by using @PathVariable

Answer (score 2):

Have a try like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/job/{j_id}/instance")
public class JobController  {
    private final String htmlDir = "job/";

    @RequestMapping(value="{i_id}/open", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView open(@PathVariable(value="j_id") Long instance_id) {
        ModelAndView result = new ModelAndView(htmlDir  + "instance");
        result.addObject("instance_id", instance_id);
        System.out.println("Instance Id -------------> " + instance_id);
        return result;
    }

}
```

Please notic "@PathVariable(value="j_id")"

To get both variables, you can change that line as following:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="{i_id}/open", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView open(@PathVariable(value="j_id") Long jnstance_id, @PathVariable(value="i_id") Long instance_id) {
            .....
    }
```